# The Cloth gets ripped apart when Cloth sim is enabled

Tags: cloth-simulation

When i am trying to simulate cloth sim into an oversized tshirt i downloaded from the internet, the tshirt starts getting ripped apart by pieces, i even enabled sewing option in the cloth sim properties. Any help would be appreciated

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Karan, welcome to BSE. Cloth simulation is pretty complex process, and it needs clean topology. I personally prefer quads for cloth - but your downloaded t-shirt has a total messy topology and i would highly recommend downloading a t-shirt with good topology or modelling your own.